# Scala unapplySeq extractor syntax

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, scala-2.11

I (inadvertently) came across a bit of pattern matching syntax I did not expect to compile and now cannot figure out.

It appears related to `unapplySeq`.

Note the `case x List(_,_)` part in this simple example:

```
val xs = List(1, 2, 3)                          //> xs  : List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

xs match {
    case x List (_, _) => "yes"
    case _             => "no"
}                                               //> res0: String = yes
```

I am used to `:` or `@` in pattern match syntax, but am confused about this. How does this syntax work and what (if any) is its relationship to `unapplySeq`?

*Sample code executed in Scala 2.11.6*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent non-infix version is:

```
xs match {
  case List(x, _, _) => "yes"
  case _             => "no"
}
```

[Scala specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html#infix-operation-patterns) says:

> An infix operation pattern p;op;q is a shorthand for the constructor
>   or extractor pattern op(p,q). The precedence and associativity of
>   operators in patterns is the same as in expressions.
>
> An infix operation pattern p;op;(q1,…,qn) is a shorthand for the
>   constructor or extractor pattern op(p,q1,…,qn).

Comment: Where do you explain how `case List(x, _, _) => "yes"` would be equivalent to `case x List(_, _) => "yes"` ?

Comment: Infix operator notation is where the method sits in between the object and and parameter (or parameters).

Comment: I thought infix notation only applied to functions with 2 arguments?? Looking at the source, `List.unapplySeq` is defined `def unapplySeq[A](x: CC[A]): Some[CC[A]] = Some(x)`

Comment: @bjfletcher: I know what infix notation is, and this does not look like it. If it was, I assume that similarly constructing a list as in `List(1,2,3)` could also be done by doing `1 List(2, 3)` (which does not make much sense, and indeed does not compile)

Comment: I cannot, for instance, write `val xs = 1 List (2, 3)` to get a `List(1, 2, 3)`

Comment: Ah ah, beat you to it ;-) Yes exactly. In addition, if infix notation is indeed supported in pattern matching, a reference would be welcome, as it is far from obvious. None of the quotes above make any mention of this.

Comment: http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html#infix-operation-patterns

Comment: Wow, that is extremely unintuitive!!!

It seems it has nothing to do with `unapplySeq` then.

Given a definition `case class Foo(a:Int, b:Int, c:Int)`, then an instance `Foo(1, 2, 3)` would match the pattern `case 1 Foo(2, 3)`.

Comment: @bjfletcher: now that's some useful reference. I canl only agree with Brian Kent,  very unintuitive indeed.